# Improve visual appearance of line of points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, points-to-line

Arcgis 10.5

I have a point shape representing a river system. It is points, not a line, because of the mathematical calculations I had to do beforehand. In close it looks like this (the actual river is there as a line shape too).

[image: points and line]

Now, I need to visualize the different values of the points. I made several categories with colors green to red. But as the next picture shows, the points are overlapping and making it very difficult to see anything if zoomed to full extent. 
I tried different sizes and different symbols. Nothing really works.

[image: overlapping points]

Any ideas what I could do? Joining it to the line would be ideal, but I dont know how, since its one big riverline and the point-values are not projected correctly to the respective part of the river.

Comment: Looks like rounding error to me, possibly caused by an improper XYPrecision vale in the SpatialReference.

Comment: As far as I know this is unavoidable because you want to map points and if you pick a smaller size, they become insignificant, if you make them bigger, they will overlap each other. The best strategy would be sorting the drawing order of your points so that you show important information over others. Say it would be quite OK to have your red dots overlaid on the others.

Comment: You can do this either by using [Symbology Levels](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/working-with-symbol-level-drawing.htm) or by physically sorting your features by [Sort tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/sort.htm).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @fatih_dur: I only have a few categories. Otherwise the colors are not distinctable from each other anyway. So that I can do manually.  But it seems there is no better way than what I am doing now. But thank you anyway!!

Comment: Can you connect "like" colors in a line? So consecutive/adjacent greens are a green line, consecutive/adjacent yellow dots are a yellow line, etc.?

Comment: @AlexS1: That would be interesting. Would you know how??

Comment: @Heiko: I'd have to think about it more... you could open up a new question with that as the focus, and you'd probably get a few clever ideas from the community. I'll think on it as well (will check out route layers for ideas), but may as well have many people thinking on it at the same time!